# How to stub rails warden spec and return 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Calling the devise session controller create method......

```
allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_throw(:warden)
post :create, params: { user: {email: 'test@test.com', password: 'error'} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code something like this

```rb
  allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})
```

and then you need to send your create request in test spec like this in order to work.

```rb
  it "gets unauthorized error" do
    allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})

    post :create, params: { user: {email: 'test@test.com', password: 'error'} }

    expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
  end
```

Make sure that your `spec_helper.rb` has:

```rb
  require 'rails_helper'
  require 'support/controller_helpers'
  require 'devise'
  ...
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    ...
    config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
    config.include ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
    ...
  end
```